# Mi consulta en php y mysqli no quiere agarrar el datos que viene por GET

Tags: php, mysqli, poo

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

archivo finalizados.php

```
$fechatwo=$_GET['fecha'];

$limit = '3';
$page = 1;
if($_POST['page'] > 1)
{
  $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
  $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
  $start = 0;
}


$query = "
SELECT * FROM trabajos WHERE estado_kal='Finalizado' AND fecha_fin='$fechatwo'
";

if($_POST['query'] != '')
{
  $query .= '
  AND equipo_kal LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'%"
  ';
}

$query .= 'ORDER BY reporte_kal DESC ';

$filter_query = $query . 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$total_data = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($filter_query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$total_filter_data = $statement->rowCount();
```

El problema es que mi variable $fechatwo=$_GET['fecha']; no trae datos o la consulta no quiere tomar datos de esa variable.

Hago el siguiente ejercicio: $fechatwo='2020-06-01'; y si funciona bien.

Que podría estar mal en el código?

Edito mi pregunta:

Aquí tengo el index.php

recibo los datos allí:

```
$fechatwo=$_GET['fecha'];

<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscador (Equipo)" autocomplete="off" />
          </div>
          <div class="table-responsive" id="dynamic_content">

        </div> 

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    load_data(1);

    function load_data(page, query = '')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"finalizados.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
      var page = $(this).data('page_number');
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(page, query);
    });

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(1, query);
    });

  });
</script>
```

y por medio de javascript traigo el archivo finalizados.php

Comment: Has probado con reemplazarlo por $_POST['fecha'] ?

Comment: Y dónde estás haciendo la petición por GET que envía la fecha? Muéstranos, por favor

Comment: @Alfabravo listo ya edite mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás invocando por POST a `finalizados.php` pero asumes que el GET persiste de una página a la otra.

`$_GET` es un array de los parámetros que llegan en la URL (e.g. `finalizados.php?fecha=20201231&var1=test`). Si al index le llega eso, no significa que se la enviará a los demás.

Cuando haces

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"finalizados.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
```

la URL es `http://alguna/ruta/finalizados.php` y no hay ningún parámetro en el GET. El script `finalizados.php` no tiene idea de lo que recibió `index.php`. Y lo mismo, `index.php` no le pasa todo el contexto de variables a `finalizados.php` a menos que lo hagas explícitamente.

Para lo que buscas, tendrías que incluir `$fechatwo` dentro de lo que le entregas a `finalizados.php`:

- sea en el mensaje por POST en un input hidden,
- en la URL (es decir, tendría que ser `finalizados.php?fecha=$fechatwo`) o
- guardándola en la sesión (y consultándola por $_SESSION).

Comment: funciona de esta manera: presiono click un boton este me lleva la fecha y la imprime en index.php, finalizados deberia tomar esa fecha tal cual cierto? pero toma el campo como vacio.

Comment: No. finalizados.php recibe por el GET lo que pongas en la URL de la petición (la tuya no tiene parámetros). Edité la respuesta a ver si se entiende

Comment: Ok hice lo siguiente:  url:"m_finalizados.php?fecha=$fechatwo", y en el archivo finalizados.php al principio coloque $fechatwo = $_SESSION['fecha']; pero aun asi no funciona. puede ser que ya estemos cerca de lograrlo.

Comment: Amigo, $_SESSION es para cuando pones el valor de la variable en sesión. Son opciones excluyentes, haces una, la otra o la otra. Si cambias la URL (segunda opción), te va a llegar en el GET. Estás comenzando recién con PHP?

Comment: Si recien comenzando pero he aprendido bastante.

Comment: Ya me funcino amigo muchas gracias :)

Comment: Te recomiendo una pasada por la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) sobre variables globales para aclarar tus dudas y que veas de qué va cada opción que te comenté.